# How do I get hot reloading to work when passing in functional components as props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-functional-component, hot-reload

**App.tsx**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Parent } from "./components/parent";
import { Child } from "./components/child";

export default function App() {
  return <Parent child={Child} />;
}
```

**Parent.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";

export const Parent: React.FC<{ child: React.FC }> = ({ child }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hot Reload Works
      {child({})}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Child.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";

export const Child: React.FC = () => {
  return <div>Hot Reload Does Not Work</div>;
};
```

How do I enable Hot Reload for my Child Functional Component when passing it as a parameter to the Parent? I've included the code sandbox that shows that hot reloading does not work in the child component.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-monad-z5fie9?file=/src/index.tsx)

Comment: Hot reloading is a feature of your server, not the composition of React components.  Are you looking for it to re-render, perhaps?

Comment: I would like it to re-render on file save instead of when refreshing the browser. In the Code Sandbox, if you edit the Parent component text and save the browsers automatically re-renders the text. if you do the same in the child component, it will not re-render, but instead you need to refresh the browser

Answer (score 1):

Hot reloading allows you to see the changes that you have made in the code without reloading your entire app. As soon as you save your code, React tracks which files have changed since your last saved, **and only reload those file for you.**

Since you are passing the `Child` component as a prop function, it will only trigger changes in `Child` and will reload it. you are not changing the `Parent` component so it wont reload the changes made in the `child({})` function.

The way to solve it is to pass the `Child` component as a `children`.

**Parent.tsx**

```js
export const Parent: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hot Reload Works
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**App.tsx**

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Child />
    </Parent>
  );
}
```

Comment: It works for one child, but what if we pass multiple children as described here https://react.dev/reference/react/Children#calling-a-render-prop-to-customize-rendering ?